I am using angular kolkov editor using formcontrol, have to bind html in my editor
html code:


<angular-editor [placeholder]="'Enter task...'" formControlName="task_note" [config]="editorConfig">
</angular-editor>    

<div class="icon" style="cursor: pointer" (click)="editTaskbtn(task)" (click)="openTask(cont)">
<img src="assets/Deals Icons/Edit icon.svg" style="height: 24px" alt="" srcset="" />
</div>



.ts file:
editorConfig: AngularEditorConfig = {
editable: true,
spellcheck: true,
height: 'auto',
minHeight: '0',
maxHeight: 'auto',
width: 'auto',
minWidth: '0',
translate: 'yes',
enableToolbar: true,
showToolbar: true,
defaultParagraphSeparator: '',
defaultFontName: '',
defaultFontSize: '',
fonts: [
{ class: 'arial', name: 'Arial' },
{ class: 'times-new-roman', name: 'Times New Roman' },
{ class: 'calibri', name: 'Calibri' },
{ class: 'comic-sans-ms', name: 'Comic Sans MS' },
],
customClasses: [
{
name: 'quote',
class: 'quote',
},
{
name: 'redText',
class: 'redText',
},
{
name: 'titleText',
class: 'titleText',
tag: 'h1',
},
],
uploadUrl: 'v1/image',
uploadWithCredentials: false,
sanitize: false,
toolbarPosition: 'top',
toolbarHiddenButtons: [
[
'undo',
'redo',
'strikeThrough',
'subscript',
'superscript',
'indent',
'outdent',
'heading',
],
[
'textColor',
'backgroundColor',
'customClasses',
'link',
'unlink',
'insertImage',
'insertVideo',
'insertHorizontalRule',
'removeFormat',
'toggleEditorMode',
],
],
};
formcontrol:
  private _initTasksForm() {
    this.tasksFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      contact_owner: ['', Validators.required],
      priority: ['', Validators.required],
      task_type: ['', Validators.required],
      task_reminder: ['', Validators.required],
      custom_reminder: [''],
      date_time: ['', Validators.required],
      task_note: ['', Validators.required],
      isClosed: [''],
    });
  }

data to be bind
{
"_id": "670cb62498a51532489dd41f",
"customer_id": "OGYCON1728883573551",
"createdBy": "OGYU1728878104362",
"type": "tasks",
"priority": "None",
"param": {
"contact_owner_unqid": "OGYU1728878104362",
"priority": "None",
"task_type": "To-do",
"task_reminder": "No reminder",
"custom_reminder": "",
"date_time": "2024-10-18T06:11:32.000Z",
"task_note": "<ul><li>tesss</li><li>decfecfc</li></ul>",
"isClosed": false,
"contact_owner": "userabc",
"contact_name": "no-name"
},
"unqid": "OGYPRO1728886308384",
"org_id": "ORG1728531905160",
"created_at": "2024-10-14T06:11:48.451Z",
"updated_at": "2024-10-14T06:11:48.451Z",
"__v": 0
}
when submitting the data using the editor data is saved as HTML, but after that when I open the editor to view the data to get edit, in angular kolkov editor data is displayed as
<ul><li>ccccc</li><li>aaaa</li><li>bbbb</li></ul>


Kindly share your Angular Reactive Forms module

private _setTasksData(task) {
     ....
    this.tasksForm?.['task_note'].setValue(
      this.transform(task.param.task_note)
    );
  }

  transform(value: any): any {
    return value.split('&lt;').join('<').split('&gt;').join('>');
  }

above code fixed my issue, code is working now.
